# Compiler doesn't like guard statement inside completion handler

Tags: swift, syntax, compiler-errors

I'm scratching my head over this one. The editor doesn't like it, and the compiler likes it even less - but they don't agree on a reason.

```
            cardRemoveTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.3, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] (_) in
                guard  let self = self else {
                    return
                }
//…
}
```

XCode editor:
Pattern matching in a condition requires the ‘case’ keyword

CardDeck.swift:31:28: Cannot convert value of type 'CardDeck?' to expected argument type '_OptionalNilComparisonType'

All I'm trying to do is avoid a forced unwrapping of self. Why can't I? If I can, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the real problem is the use of `self` as a variable name.  `self` is a reserved keyword in Swift, so use something else, perhaps `uself`:

```
cardRemoveTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.3, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
    guard let uself = self else { return }

    // use uself
}
```

**Note:**  You can surround `self` with backticks (``) to use it as a variable name, but I wouldn't recommend it because you'd have to do that everywhere you use it.  It's easier to just use another variable name.

Comment: OK. I'll mark it answered. But I still think the code should be valid as is. (as in why is 'self' a special variable name that can't be used...)

Comment: @Mozahler You can certainly use `self`, if you surround it with backticks in your code, i.e. `\`self\``. But it's not really a good design choice, and you'll need to use the backticks everywhere you use it.

Comment: `self` is a Swift keyword with special meaning.  You can use it as a general variable name by surrounding it with backticks, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @vacawama Ahaha indeed! You must have posted yours at virtually the same time as mine.

Comment: I forgot all about that! It's not something I'd want to get into the habit of doing. But I should at least remember there's reason the option is there.. Thanks, guys!

Comment: Indeed.  I think the posts were 2 seconds apart.

Comment: I didn't get a notification from Soren, only vacawama. Maybe you don't get notified if you're on the page? I'm not sure how that works.